# What are the advantages of upgrading to a 32 bit microcontroller?

Tags: electronics

I returned my 3D printer controller board since it died, after only doing a dozen failed/successful prints.

I have bought myself a [RADDS board](http://doku.radds.org/dokumentation/radds/) which set me back £72 including motor drivers but not the Arduino Due.

Will I see some real benefit in upgrading to 32 bit because surely it doesn't make it print faster?